# Apache 8.5 rejects encoded url

Tags: apache, tomcat, url, encoding

I have a URL formed like https://dev.server.org/documents/here_goes_the_query/related?someInfo&someInfo

I am now trying to pass a by Java encoded String to the url like:

https://dev.server.org/documents/word%20anotherWord/related?someInfo&someInfo

(also word+anotherWord)

As long there is no encoded stuff, it works pretty well. But any other encoded character i got a 404. Any suggestion whats causing that?

Comment: What is your code? What is mapped to that URL, and how?

Comment: On the server side is a apache tomcat 8.5, holding a RESTful Java application. But this application is never reached, because apache is rejecting it beforehand. It saying bad request and gives a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It was in fact the Java Program at the very beginning.

@Path("documents/{documentId : [a-zA-Z0-9-_.,*%*]+}")

I just added here the % sign, what was not allowed before.